# Google Analytics for multiple sites

Tags: google-analytics

So Im using a single google analytics code for multiple domains. But now the domain owners want to see the stats themselves by logging in. My question is, is it possible to give access to my account and only have the stats show for their domain? Or do I have to create seperate accounts for each domain and add their tracking code along with mine on the pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but this depends on what you have done already.

Are you using the same tracking code/ID on multiple sites?  If so, you have completely corrupted your data, and it is now essentially useless to you.  You should start over.

Or, are you using multiple sites under one Google Analytics account?  If that is the case, there is hope for you:

Simply log into Google Analytics, and at the bottom you will see "User Manager".  Click that, and you can click "Add User" at the top right.

There are two kinds of "Access Type":

- View reports only
- Account administrator

Account administrators can do everything in an account.  You are an account administrator.

For viewing reports only, you can assign users specific domains.  This is how you would let your clients in to view their reports.

[image]

Personally, I find it best to create a separate Google Analytics account for each client.  This way, if they ever decide to pick a new person to do their web work, they can just take the whole account with them.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the info! The reason I ask because in the main account I do event tracking and I didnt want to have to add additional event tracking for each new account. Do you know if I give them access to reports only they have access to the event tracking as well for that domain?

Comment: @John, yes, if they are able to view reports, they are able to see everything in the report.

Comment: @Brad One more question, I notice in the screenshot above it says available website profiles. So I have to create a website profile for each site? Doesnt that require an additional tracking code if I create a profile?

Comment: @John, that is correct.  If you aren't already using multiple website profiles, your data is absolutely FUBAR and you should start over with a fresh account.  You absolutely cannot use multiple sites with one tracking account.  Your data will be a mess, and of no use to you.

Comment: @Brad wait how is that fubar if I want to track all sites under one tracking code? I want to see a total of all reporting and tracking under one account. Google doesnt allow you to merge multiple profiles together. Right now I can get all reporting based on hostname.

Comment: @John, if you are happy with looking at your data by hostname, then that's fine, but I honestly think that makes a mess of things.  When you look at your content reports for example, unless you filter it out, you see everything!  How can you manage individual sites with data from all of them in one place?  If you want to see an overview of all your sites, you can do so on the main dashboard, or externally.

Comment: @Brad so there is a way in google analytics to look at a report with multiple profiles at once? I want to see the graphs for all sites, perhaps I want to run a report that just shows 2 sites instead of all of the sites. Can I do that with multiple profiles at once?

Comment: @John, not built in, no.  There is basic information on the dashboard when you login.  If you need such an overview, you can use Excellent Analytics in Excel to pull in your GA data.

Comment: @Brad I see. I currently use a php class that allows me to access google analytics api. I can pass filters that says give me vistors/impressions/events with hostname containing this site and or another site. That is why I have all one tracking code, as well as for event tracking. I didnt want to go in and out of different profiles to get this information. Perhaps the best solution is to have one tracking code for all sites then create different profiles for individual sites for the user to access and just have 2 tracking codes on the site.

Comment: @John, that sounds like a horrifying mess... but to each their own I guess.

Comment: @Brad Whats messy about it? The actual management of it or the data storage? If I have one overall tracking code tracking all click events for all sites then have individual profiles that just do normal tracking why would that be a mess? Im not saying its not Im just interested as to why so I dont have it become a horrifying mess.

Comment: @John, well for one, you are now unable to properly assign permissions so your clients can access their analytics data.  At the very least, when you try to use your data, you have mixed up data for all of your domains all in one account.  Perhaps this isn't a problem for you, but I cannot imagine a context where it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Brad One of the requirements is they, they being my superiors, need to go in and see network wide how the traffic looks. Not for individual sites but all sites at once. They want the graph as well not just a number. Also I need to track events throughout all sites, if I do that per profile then when running reports via the api I will have to go in and out of different profiles. The bottom line is they want the best of both worlds. A cumulative of all sites on the network and then a break down per site. This was the only solution I could come up with.

Answer (score -1):

If you do use one tag, you can then also sort them with a custom report based on hostname.  This link will ad a custom report to your google analytics profile: https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=9aFNlMl9RLuEJdiXsqMEcQ

Answer (score -1):

You can also combine two approaches together. Create one UA (profile, tracking code) for global profile and one for each of the individual sites. Then you can insert **both** tracking code for the global profile and individual site profile on the same page. The tracking will be done twice and separately into two profiles.

Or if you do use **multiple profiles** and want to have the overview of your sites - check http://gachart.appointment.at/.